# select element and make it first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

when I click on three I want it to be like:-

```
<ul>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove and prepend...

Comment: Please add some codes that you tried so far, and we'll help you debug it.

Answer (score 5):

If you have jQuery you can use:

```js
$('#items li').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = "items">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

I can also write a non-jQuery one up if needed.

Answer (score 1):

handle click event with use of `remove()` and `prepend()` method.

```js
$("body").on("click",'li',function(){
$('ul').prepend($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: why do you need a loop and why do you need remove?

Comment: You don't need either - you can directly append/prepend a DOM object without worrying about it being cloned and the loop is completely superfluous

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
        $('#list li').on('click', function () {
            var index = $('li').index(this);
            if (index !== 0) {
                $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <ul id="list" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```